# Square with midpoints of $AD$ and $CD$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

> Square $ABCD$ is given; $MA=MD=ND=NC$. Show $AF=AB$.
>   [image]

The first thing I noticed was $\triangle CDM \cong \triangle BCN$ and we obtain $CM = BN$ and $\angle MCD = \angle NBC$. Now I am trying to show $\angle BFM = 90 ^\circ$ but I am having difficulties with this and don't know if it will help with the solution. Would appreciate help of any kind!

Edit: Thank you for your help! Now I see how $\angle BFM = 90^\circ$. $\angle BAM + \angle BFM = 180 ^\circ$, thus $ABFM$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Does this help?

Comment: $\angle BFM=\angle CFN=180^\circ-\angle MCD-\angle CNB=180^\circ-\angle MCD -\angle CMD=90^\circ$.

Comment: For this problem, I think the analytic method will my first choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be a center of a square.

Notice that rotation around $S$ for $90^{\circ}$ takes $BN$ to $CM$ ($B\mapsto C$, $C\mapsto D$ ... and since $DM = CN$ we have $N\mapsto M$) so $\angle BFM = 90^{\circ}$.

Now we see that $ABFM$ is cyclic, so $$<AFB = <AMB = <DMC = 90-<DCM = 90-<CBN = < ABF$$

So $ABF$ is isosceles.

Comment: I can not believe. Nobody can see simplitines of this aproach.

Comment: If I remember, $B \mapsto C$ because $SB = SC$ and $\angle BSC = 90 ^\circ$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @AndrewRogers

Comment: And the angle between $BN$ and $CM$ is equal to the angle of rotation. Is there a theorem about this because I haven't read this in my book? I know it from the problems I've solved.

Comment: Yes it is obviuously, if we rotate line $p$ to line $q$, then angle between them is a rotational angle.

Comment: OK. I am asking because when I asked my teacher she said that I have to prove it every time I use it. :)

Comment: This is a theorem you could easly prove it your self.

Comment: Here is another example, say we have squares $ABCD$ and $A'B'C'D$ then angle between $AA'$ and $CC'$ is also 90 and they are congruent.

Comment: When I first started reading this answer I thought "the statement" was $AF=AB.$ Only later did I realize "the statement" was $\angle BFM = 90^\circ$.

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: I do not understand why is this a problem.

Comment: @AndrewRogers I don’t know why you directed that comment to me, but $\angle ABF$ is just another name for $\angle ABN,$ and $\angle ABN+\angle NBC=\angle ABC.$

Comment: Silly me! Got it! @DavidK, I don't know. It's a bit late in my country. Sorry for this.

Comment: Why are you refering me as David K?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are perpendicular.  $\angle BNC \cong \angle CMD$ by CPCTC, and therefore $\triangle CFN \sim \triangle CDM$ and thus $\angle CFN$ is a right angle.

Moving on from there, let's just draw parallels to BM and CN through A, B, C, and D.

[image]

From this, it should be pretty clear that $AB=AF$.

Comment: Yes, this "like mad" approach creates plenty of congruent triangles which then add up to what we want!

Comment: Thank you for your response! Can you see the edit to tell me if I can continue my idea?

Comment: @Andrew Rogers It's not clear to me how a cyclic quadrilateral will help.  You could use Ptolemy's Theorem if you knew FM and FB, but I don't know how those would be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

Extend $FM$ and $AB$ to meet at $K$.

Thus, since $\measuredangle KFB=90^{\circ}$ and $FA$ is a median of $\Delta KFB,$ we obtain:
$$KA=AB=FA$$ and we are done!

Comment: Well done! :) It looks so simple.

Comment: @Andrew Rogers Nice problem!

Comment: @Andrew Rogers See the farruhota's picture. It must help.

Comment: How do we know $A$ is the midpoint of $KB$?

Comment: Oh, $\triangle AMK \cong CDM$.

Comment: @Andrew Rogers $\Delta AMK\cong\Delta DMC.$

Answer (score 1):

Drop perpendicular $AG$ and denote $\angle ABG=x$:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Note:
$$x=\angle ABG=\angle BNC \quad \text{(because $AB||CD$})\\
\angle CFN=90^\circ \quad \text{(because $\Delta CFN\sim \Delta CDM$)} \\
\Delta ABG\cong \Delta BCF \quad \text{(because correspondig angles and one side are equal)}\\
BF=2CF=4FN \quad \text{(because $\tan x=2$)}\\
FG=BF-BG=2CF-BG=2BG-BG=BG.$$
So, the perpendicular $AG$ is also median, hence $\Delta AFB$ is an isosceles triangle and $AF=AB$.

Comment: Thank you! What is $\tan$?

Comment: $\tan x=\tan \angle CMD=\frac{CD}{DM}=2$